# AdColony V4VC dialog not responding on Amazon Kindle Fire

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, kindle-fire, adcolony

On a Kindle Fire HD, when a user taps an optional ad view button to earn in-game currency, the AdColony V4VC confirmation dialog pops up. However, it is unresponsive, and UI events seem to pass through it to my game's UI still (I can tap other buttons and interact with my game). So an ad never plays, and you can't cancel out of the dialog. Once the dialog is visible, the only way to make it go away is to quit the app. There is no error or warning message being output to ADM. My configure string is appVersion = "version:1.12,store:amazon"

I've got AdColony working on iOS and Google (Android) builds of the same game, utilizing a universal wrapper for the AdColony SDK. So I know my side of the code path and callbacks are all correct... something is going wrong with the AdColony code on Amazon devices. Amazon review team has also confirmed this happens on all Kindle variants, so it's not just one particular device. Any one else seen this or have any ideas?

Comment: I should have noted I'm using the latest AdColony Unity package:
Modified: February 23th, 2015
Unity Plug-in Version: 2.0.5
iOS SDK Version: 2.5.0
Android SDK Version: 2.2.1

Comment: To add to the mystery, I also have another game using an older version of the AdColony Unity package that DOES work on Amazon devices... using almost identical code and setup.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest plugin from AdColony and then look at your android manifest directory and be sure you have the following:

```
<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
```

This worked for me on Kindle and Samsung.